# How do you stop repeating the same character or name?

Tags: python, csv

This is my first time i am doing programming and using stack overflow.

For the program i am doing, it generates a list of anime recommendations by going through a survey style questions. Having a CSV file storing info about the anime such as the genre.

However, when going through the program, it prints the same anime.

Basically, let's say that Pokemon is an action and comedy anime and the user says they like both genre. It prints out the Pokemon twice. In summary, I want to stop it from duplicating. Also, idk if i'm doing this right or if there is a simpler way of doing my program. Idk if i need to improve on annotations.

Here's my program so far:

```
import csv

#in the csv AnimeGenre3.csv it contains information such as the animes, the number of episodes and genres

#printing information about the program.
#has an if statement to identify if it user wants to start the program.

looping1 = True

print('This is a program that identifies specfic anime for you')

while looping1 == True:
    begin = str(input('Do you like to start; yes or no: '))
    
    if begin == 'yes':
        print('''
Let's begin
''')
        break
    if begin == 'no':
        print('thank you for coming')
    else:
        print('''
    Sorry Man got to do it again
            ''')
#this section is where the program ask the user questions from there
# it will identify, the genres the user is interested in.
looping2 = True

while looping2 == True:
    
    action = str(input('Do you like action; yes or no: '))
    adventure = str(input('Do you like adventure; yes or no: '))
    comedy = str(input('Do you like comedy; yes or no: '))
    documentary = str(input('Do you like documentary; yes or no: '))
    drama = str(input('Do you like drama; yes or no: '))
    fanservice = str(input('Do you like fan service; yes or no: '))
    fantasy = str(input('Do you like fantasy; yes or no: '))
    gaming = str(input('Do you like gaming; yes or no: '))
    historical = str(input('Do you like historical; yes or no: '))
    horror = str(input('Do you like horror; yes or no: '))
    idol = str(input('Do you like idol; yes or no: '))
    isekai = str(input('Do you like isekai; yes or no: '))
    kids = str(input('Do you like kids; yes or no: '))
    magicalgirl = str(input('Do you like magical girl; yes or no: '))
    martialarts = str(input('Do you like matrtial arts; yes or no: '))
    mecha = str(input('Do you like mecha; yes or no: '))
    mystery = str(input('Do you like mystery; yes or no: '))
    romance = str(input('Do you like romance; yes or no: '))
    school = str(input('Do you like school; yes or no: '))
    scifi = str(input('Do you like sci fi; yes or no: '))
    shonen = str(input('Do you like shonen; yes or no: '))
    sliceoflife = str(input('Do you like slice of life; yes or no: '))
    space = str(input('Do you like space; yes or no: '))
    sports = str(input('Do you like sport; yes or no: '))
    superpower = str(input('Do you like super power; yes or no: '))
    supernatual = str(input('Do you like supernatual; yes or no: '))
    magic = str(input('Do you like magic; yes or no: '))
    physiochogical = str(input('Do you like physichogical; yes or no: '))
    thriller = str(input('Do you like thriller; yes or no: '))
    print('')
    print('Recommended Anime List:')
   #having to use if statements to find any anime that either say "yes" in the csv file
    # it sorts out all of the sorts that the useer said yes to.
    # It goes through the rows to identify all of user genres that say yes
    # it should print out the recommend anime
    # this prints out a long list of anime
    
    if action == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[3] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False
                    print(' *', anime)
         
    if adventure == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[4] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False
                    print(' *', anime)
    
    if comedy == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[5] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if documentary == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[7] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if drama == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[8] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if fanservice == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[9] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
    
    if fantasy == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[10] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if gaming == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[11] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if historical == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[12] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if horror == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[13] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if idol == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[14] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if isekai == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[15] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if kids == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[16] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if magicalgirl == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[17] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if martialarts == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[18] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if mecha == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[19] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if mystery == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[20] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if romance == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[21] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if school == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[22] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if scifi == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[23] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if shonen == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[24] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if sliceoflife == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[25] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if space == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[26] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if sports == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[27] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if superpower == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[28] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if supernatual == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[29] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if magic == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[30] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if physiochogical == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[31] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if thriller == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[32] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
    else:
        print('''
    There seems to be a problem in one of the questions
            ''')
    # if there is an sytax error within the program, it should pop up to the user saying this
        
    StartAgain = str(input('Do you like to start again; yes or no: '))
    
    if StartAgain == 'yes':
        print('''
Let's begin
''')
        break
    if StartAgain == 'no':
        print('thank you for coming')
    
    else:
        print('''
    Sorry Man got to do it again''')
    
    # an if statement if user wants to start again
    # this should run the program again.
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Jono

Comment: Could you add to your post the code that you're running? That way it will be a lot easier to read and understand what the problem is.

Comment: ok, but how do i do that?

Comment: It's kinda of terrible

Comment: this is my first time so, it may be confusing.

Comment: Do post it. ---

Comment: Ok just put my program up Leandro Esteban and Ann Zen

Comment: Also do i put my csv file as well

Comment: Instead of print, put it on a set, then print the set at the end.

Comment: how do i do that by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the way it is right now it'll print any anime as many times as they fulfill a requirement, so if Pokemon is, as stated in your example, as action and comedy, when the user inputs yes in both fields it will print twice. That happens so because when you established your `if genre==True` you check on them individually and print all the results each gender has. There are quite a few ways to deal with that. One of them is by using a list of animes, so, you could add near the beginning of your code a `anime_list = []` (which is an empty list), and then inside your if statements change the output to this:

```
if genre == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[3] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False
                    # Down here's the modification
                    if anime not in anime_list:
                        anime_list.append(anime)
```

By adding them to a list and then checking if it's already inside the list, by the end of your program when you run `print(anime_list)` you'll get the same results but only once per anime. That should solve your current problem.

There are also a couple things you'd want to try to improve your coding. A simple one is that when you use `input`, the default output is a `str`, so while not wrong, the `str(input)` is not necessary. Now for more useful stuff, generally speaking, if you find yourself repeating similar lines many times it means there's very likely a simpler way to do it. For instance, you're running separate code for every genre but they all do exactly the same, so if you can somehow read all the genres and place them inside a `for` loop, you'll find out that those 100 lines will soon turn into 7, thus making it far quicker once you want to modify it.

Comment: how would i make it more simpler using the for loop?